# Suspenders detaching unexpectedly from pants

Tags: clothing, fastener

Due to an increasing waistline I have recently started using suspenders. They work well EXCEPT that I have to attach the clips over the belt loops as the  extra cloth makes for a more secure attachment. Now it is fairly rare that a  clip will fly off. However most belt loops are not evenly spaced -- not centered in the rear or evenly spaced in the front. How can I increase the gripping power of my suspender clips so I can place them wherever I choose?

Comment: Something might be wrong with the clips on the suspenders. Often, the clip will become distorted due to being used on fabric that is too thick. When this happens, it is possible to "fix" the slight bend to grab thinner cloth. Look carefully at the clips to determine where to make the "repair."

Comment: Suspenders with plastic “teeth” are half as reliable as full metal clips. I had the same problem with plastic clips. I tried repeatedly to make them work, because I like that they don’t start tearing into fabric like metal ones, but I’m ready to go back to ruined waist bands after weeks of frustration.

Comment: I do the same thing; place them over my belt loops (which is not ideal as the loops aren't evenly spaced). However they do a better job with my overextended belly than belts. Seems that once you reach a certain size a belt just pushes your pants off the belly dome. Damn gravity!

Answer (score 6):

You could sew small buttons onto your pants' waistlines at the positions you like to clip the suspenders. Then you fasten the clip *over* the buttons each time. Since the buttons stick out from the fabric, the clips will have a lot of extra "grip".